# How can I execute php scripts on Nanohttpd?

Tags: php, android, nanohttpd

Iam new to WebServer and iam using NanoHttpd , Everything work fine and i can connect to my phone using my web browser on my Computer, my problem is that iam trying to run a Php file manager app, called 'fsmanager' , work fine on my website i can browse my files etc, in my index.html i have a simple  tag that target fsmanager.php, when i click it, im asked to download the php file, i have tried to add mime type php application/php etc with no luck, source code is same as NanoHttpd,

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at "Quercus" (http://quercus.caucho.com/) from the folks who make the Resin App-Server.  Its a complete implementation of PHP version 5 that runs on the JVM, as a servlet.

While NanoHttpd doesnt support the servlet API specifically, I am sure that you could write hooks to and from *Quercus* to get something running with NanoHttpd.  That would be a fabulous extension to the existing webserver code!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

nanohttpd is purely an HTTP server, it will not execute PHP files on it's own.